# Headers with Flink Table Api Kafka Sink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-table-api

How does one send kafka headers with the table api in Flink? I used the sql syntax to create a sink but not sure how to include custom headers.

Comment: Using the key property in the kafka record to get my solution going but would ideally like to use the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's currently possible is described [here in the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#available-metadata). The only writable metadata fields are the timestamp and the headers, where the headers are exposed as a map of strings to raw bytes.

For an example, see [testKafkaSourceSinkWithMetadata](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/44f73c496ed1514ea453615b77bee0486b8998db/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/KafkaTableITCase.java#L272) from the Flink sources.

Excerpting from that example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE kafka (
  ...,
  `headers` MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  ...
)


INSERT INTO kafka
VALUES
  (..., MAP['k1', X'C0FFEE', 'k2', X'BABE01']),
  (..., CAST(NULL AS MAP<STRING, BYTES>),
  (..., MAP['k1', X'102030', 'k2', X'203040'])
```